# Floating action button above scrollView

Tags: android, floating-action-button

[image]

How can i position floating button above Scrollview layout...i have tried to position Scrollview and the container of the button(FrameLayout) inside Relative layout but this approach also is not working...
xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="100">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/no_size"
    android:layout_weight="92">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/questionContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.rey.material.widget.TextView
            android:id="@+id/surveyTitleTtv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <com.rey.material.widget.TextView
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:textColor="@color/accentColor"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheetLlt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <com.rey.material.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/saveQuestionBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:text="ADD"
        app:elevation="2dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Please can anyone tell me what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i have managed to resolve the issue..the problem was that i was trying to place FAB inside fragment layout which obviously turned out to be not feasible. I moved it inside my activity xml layout as a child of CoordinatorLayout and now is actually a 'floating' action button...

Answer (score 0):

Just move your `FloatingButton` above scroll view in xml layout

Answer (score 0):

You need to position a `FloatingActionButton` within a `CoordinatorLayout` and use the CoordinatorLayout as the root of your Activity. (FloatingActionButton relies on features which the CoordinatorLayout enables) If your scrollview is a inside a fragment, this is still alright - so long as you assign an ID to the FloatingActionButton you can reference it from inside the fragment.

Comment: i have just tried it..but it is still hiding below bottomSheetLlt FrameLayout

Comment: please post all layout files which are related to what the user see is seeing. We can revise.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your xml code with below code. You need to use Relative Layout or Coordinator Layout as root layout. And simply put floatig action button outside of framelayout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/questionContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.rey.material.widget.TextView
            android:id="@+id/surveyTitleTtv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <com.rey.material.widget.TextView
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:textColor="@color/accentColor"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

<com.rey.material.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/saveQuestionBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:text="ADD"
    app:elevation="2dp" />
```